# Moving window on categorical value with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series like this :

```
s = pd.Series(["A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C"])
```

I'd like to have the count or proportion of each letter in a non overlapping window of size 4.

I tried with this :

```
pd.rolling_apply(s, 4, pd.value_counts)
```

But it does not work.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: C
```

Any idea to perform this task ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your series uses a `RangeIndex`, you can create your non-overlapping windows by dividing by their size:

```
print(s.index // 4)
# => Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], dtype='int64')
```

Group by the above and use `.value_counts()`:

```
s.groupby(s.index // 4).value_counts()

# 0  A    2
#    B    1
#    C    1
# 1  A    2
#    C    2
# 2  B    3
#    A    1
# 3  A    2
#    C    1
# dtype: int64
```

If you prefer proportions instead of counts, give `.value_counts()` the argument `normalize=True`:

```
s.groupby(s.index // 4).value_counts(normalize=True)

# 0  A    0.500000
#    B    0.250000
#    C    0.250000
# 1  A    0.500000
#    C    0.500000
# 2  B    0.750000
#    A    0.250000
# 3  A    0.666667
#    C    0.333333
# dtype: float64
```

If your series had a different kind of index, you could still generate the windows as follows:

```
pd.Series(range(len(s))) // 4

# 0     0
# 1     0
# 2     0
# 3     0
# 4     1
# 5     1
# 6     1
# 7     1
# 8     2
# 9     2
# 10    2
# 11    2
# 12    3
# 13    3
# 14    3
# dtype: int64
```

Any of the following two lines result in the same output as above:

```
s.groupby(pd.Series(range(len(s))) // 4).value_counts()
s.groupby(pd.Series(range(len(s))) // 4).value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice puzzle!
I use a for loop to get a dictionary of all windows. Then I build a DataFrame, then I can use value_counts(). Is this what you asked for?

```
In [150]: winsize = 4

In [151]: for i in range(len(s)+1-winsize): wd[i] = s[i:i+winsize].tolist()

In [152]: wd
Out[152]: 
{0: ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
 1: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
 2: ['B', 'C', 'A', 'C'],
 3: ['C', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
 4: ['A', 'C', 'A', 'C'],
 5: ['C', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
 6: ['A', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
 7: ['C', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
 8: ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
 9: ['B', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
 10: ['B', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
 11: ['B', 'A', 'A', 'C']}

In [153]: pd.DataFrame(wd)
Out[153]: 
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11
0  A  A  B  C  A  C  A  C  A  B  B  B
1  A  B  C  A  C  A  C  A  B  B  B  A
2  B  C  A  C  A  C  A  B  B  B  A  A
3  C  A  C  A  C  A  B  B  B  A  A  C

In [154]: pd.DataFrame(wd).apply(pd.value_counts)
Out[154]: 
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
A   2   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   2   2
B   1   1   1 NaN NaN NaN   1   2   3   3   2   1
C   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1 NaN NaN NaN   1
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. I just wanted non overlapping window, but that's not a pb I guess, you just need to add a step in the range.